# In JavaScript, why does 4 + 3 + 2 + "1" = "91" if the + (plus) operator is right-associative?

Tags: javascript

The JS spec seems to say two things:

1. When a number and a string are added, the number is coerced into a string, and the two strings are concatenated. `"2" + 7 == "27"` and `2 + "7" == "27"` are both true.
2. The `+` operator is right-associative.

If `+` is right-associative, then I would expect chained addition operations like `4 + 3 + 2 + "1"` to be evaluated like `4 + (3 + (2 + "1"))`, and for the logic to be

1. `2 + "1"` evaluates to `"21"`
2. `3 + "21"` evaluates to `"321"`
3. `4 + "321" evaluates to "4321"`

But instead, the expression evaluates to `"91"`, like it's doing `4 + 3 = 7`, `7 + 2 = 9`, `9 + "1" = "91"`.

What have I misunderstood or missed?

Comment: Addition is left-to-right associative according to [this table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table). You might be confusing it with unary plus.

Comment: _The JS spec seems to say two things ... The `+` operator is right-associative_... where?

Comment: @JohnMontgomery is right, I mixed up addition and unary plus, which I was unfamiliar with. My bad.